# psycopg2 each execute yields different table and cursor not scrolling to the beginning

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

I am querying a postgresql database through python's psycopg2 package.

In short: The problem is `psycopg2.fetchmany()` yields a different table everytime I run a `psydopg2.cursor.execute()` command.

```
import psycopg2 as ps
conn = ps.connect(database='database', user='user')
nlines = 1000
tab = "some_table" 
statement= """ SELECT * FROM """ + tab + " LIMIT %d;" %(nlines)
crs.execute(statement)
```

then I fetch the data in pieces. Running the following executes just fine and each time when I scroll back to the beginning I get the same results.

```
rec=crs.fetchmany(10)
crs.scroll(0, mode='absolute')
print rec[-1][-2]
```

However, if I run the `crs.execute(statement)` again and then fetch the data, it yields a completely different output. I tried running `ps.connect` again, do `conn.rollback(), conn.reset(), crs.close()` and nothing ever resulted in consisted output from the table. I also tried a named cursor with scrollable enabled

```
crs= conn.cursor(name="cur1")
crs.scrollable=1
...
crs.scroll(0, mode= 'absolute')
```

still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any `ORDER BY` clause in your query, and *Postgres* does not guarantee any particular ordering without one. It's particularly likely to change ordering for tables which have lots of churn (i.e. lots of inserts/updates/deletes).

See the *Postgres* [`SELECT` doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) for more details, but the most salient snippet here is this:

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in
>   the specified order. If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned
>   in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.

I wouldn't expect any query, regardless of the type of cursor used, to necessarily return the exact same result set given a query of this type.

What happens when you add an explicit `ORDER BY`?